# Partition data when reading file in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, shuffle

I am new to Spark. Consider the following code:

```
val rdd = sc
  .objectFile[(Int, Int)]("path")
  .partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(sc.defaultParallelism))
  .persist()
rdd.count()
```

Is each tuple read from the file directly sent to the its partition specified by the hash partitioner? Or is it that the whole file is first read into memory without considering the partitioner and then distributed according to the partitioner. To me, the former may be more efficient since the data is shuffled once while the latter needs two shuffles.

Comment: RDDs are legacy in reality.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the comments in the code

```
val rdd = sc
  .objectFile[(Int, Int)]("path") // Loads the whole file with default minimum partitions and default partitioner
  .partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(sc.defaultParallelism)) // Re-partitions the RDD using HashPartitioner
  .persist()
```

Comment: Will Spark optimize the code to the first case in question?

Comment: Spark lazily loads the file until the action is performed on the RDD/ Dataframe / Dataset and I have face OOMs due to huge file.

Comment: Right. Suppose we now call `rdd.count()`, I wonder how Spark optimizes the code. This is, will each tuple be sent directly to the partition specified by HashPartitioner?

Comment: all the executor will report there count and driver would sum and output it. But before that all data will be read by Driver and partitioned across executors

Comment: Spark wont optimize the code. Spark uses Parquet file format internally for it computation which a complete set of metadata at the header and bottom part of each partitioned file. Hence spark need not scan while file for count.